# Promoting the Site at Events

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I know this came up before the SPC, but I wanted to bring it up again.  Lets get some good ideas for promoting the site and its members at various SharePoint events.  I'm hanging out at a SharePoint Saturday event today and found it amazing how many of the SP.SE guys are here.

It would be great to find a way to identify contributors and bring in some more people.

Comment: +1:Really Good Idea! I wish I could have joined it as well :)

Answer (score 1):

This could be a session topic for a SharePoint Saturday presentation. The abstract for the talk could focus on the lone SP guy in an organization tasked with implementing a SP site for his company/group/project and that he is not alone.  There is a community of people to talk to when he runs into a problem.

The agenda would be an overview of the SE structure and purpose of the SE community (Joel and Jeff's vision for the SE sites).  How to ask questions. How to find answers. Discussion of the community and what reputation means.

I think an hour talk about this could be interesting to people just getting into the SP community.  I would be the first to say it is not as glamorous a subject as some latest coding technique, but it is still important for SPSE and the SP Saturday community.

If this sounds promising, I would be willing to give this a try at our SPS Philly, which is currently taking submissions for their event in February.  I would also be willing to share or collaborate with the other SPSE members on the agenda and slidedeck so we can have a consistent message about the site.

Comment: I think this is a great idea. Alternatively, tack a few minutes SP.SE on to the end of a talk on almost any SP subject at a user group meeting.

Answer (score 0):

It's SharePoint Saturday UK a week today in Nottingham. I'll be wearing my SPSE T-shirt. Any other suggestions?